# Change color of THIS element

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a calendar which contains a same `class` for every day. I would like to change color of class(some box in table) which contains a character "C" inside. I'm able to find it using `jquery` but when I try to change it, it changes every element with that `class` so I'm trying to use `this` but it wont work... Here is the code

```
   if(($(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a").text()).includes("C")){
     $(this).css("background-color","red");
   }
```

I tried this as well, but it changed every element with that `class`

```
   var aaa = $(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a")
   if(aaa.text().includes("C")){
     aaa.css("background-color","red");
   }
```

Comment: [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) will return the text of every matched element. You will have to loop through the elements with [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Or you use [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) and pass a function as the second parameter (-> [`.css(propertyName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)), where the function then is called for every element in the collection.

Comment: @Andreas thank you, could you please write me a example for the `.each()` or `.css()` how could I use it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the **aaa** contains all element that satisfies the selector condition (.tribe-events-month-event-title > a). So if any of them includes **C** you are applying `aaa.css("background-color","red");` which makes all **aaa** elements turn red. What you have to do is loop through each **aaa** element and check the condition.

```
var aaa = $(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a")
 aaa.each(function(e) {
   if($(this).text().includes("C")){
     $(this).css("background-color","red");
   }
 })
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/bGGooLz

Comment: You know you can make a _snippet_ here just clicking on `[<>]` in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a handy [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo selector:

```js
$(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a:contains('C')")
  .css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `:contains` to avoid looping:

```js
 var elements = $(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a:contains('C')");
elements.css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a href="#">A</a>
</div>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a href="#">C</a>
</div>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a href="#">C</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` or `:contains` are the most elegant here

```js
$(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a").filter(function() {
   return $(this).text().includes("C");
 }).css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a:contains('C')").css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've proposed to use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each) and [`.css(propertyName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/css/).
As there is already an answer for `.each()` I'm only going to add the `.css()` one:

> `.css( propertyName, function )`
>
> `propertyName`
>       Type: `String`
>       A CSS property name.
>
> `function`
>       Type: `Function( Integer index, String value )` => `String` or `Number`
>       A function returning the value to set. `this` is the current element.
>       Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

```js
$(".tribe-events-month-event-title > a")
  .css("background-color", function(_, oldValue) {
    if ($(this).text().includes("C")) {
      return "red";
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tribe-events-month-event-title">
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `return $(this).text().includes("C") ? "red" : null`

Comment: @mplungjan _"If nothing is returned in the setter function (ie. `function( index, style ){}` ), or if `undefined` is returned, **the current value is not changed**. This is useful for selectively setting values only when certain criteria are met"_

Comment: I know. Hence the null. I just find the ternary more elegant than the if